# dlmwrite printing a 3D matrix for every x-dimension line

Tags: matlab, matrix

Currently my matrix has the size of (40x50x60), and when I write it out with `dlmwrite`, it writes a line for every x and the line is 50*60 long.
I need to write the same matrix but the lines should be 40 numbers long.
So i just need to divide the long lines with 40 and print a new line after 40 numbers and so on.
And the numbers should have the delimiter '\t'.

Right now im using:

```
dlmwrite('matlaboutput', matrix, '\t')
```

Is there something I can add to the command or should i use a different command for the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may `reshape` the `matrix` to have 40 columns and then write it

```
dlmwrite('matlaboutput', reshape( matrix, [], 40 ), '\t' );
```

Comment: That did exactly what I needed!
Thank you!